# <Box> Element causing overflows on smaller screens, even though it does not reach the end of the screen. Material UI React & Webpack

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, material-ui

On smaller screens my react box component makes the screen "expand" on the right side, and this causes the navbar to expand, and also horizontal scroll to appear, I have attached my return code, and also a few screenshots that may help.

My element

```
    return (
    <div>
        {/* Name "input" panel */}
        <Container>
            <Box
                sx={{
                    maxWidth: { xs: 350, sm: 480, md: 600, lg: 800},
                    borderWidth: 15,
                    borderStyle: 'solid',
                    borderColor: 'background.paper',
                    borderRadius: 4,
                    boxShadow: 8,
                    backgroundColor: 'background.paper',
                    '&:hover': {
                        backgroundColor: 'background.paper',
                        opacity: [0.98, 0.93, 0.9],
                    },
                }}
            >
                <Typography variant="h4" sx={{fontWeight: 700}}>Enter the name you'd like to look up </Typography>

                <FormControl sx={{ m: 2, width: '26ch' }} variant="outlined">
                    <OutlinedInput id="filled-basic" type="text" label="VinuPay Name" variant="filled" sx={{paddingBottom: 2}}  error={!isValid} onChange={(event) => {checkNameValidity(event.target.value)}} endAdornment={<InputAdornment position="end">.vinu</InputAdornment>}/>
                    <InputLabel htmlFor="filled-adornment-amount">VinuPay Name</InputLabel>
                    <Typography variant="h6" display={reasonId === undefined ? "none" : "block"} color={isValid ? "#1eff18" : "#ff0000"}>{isValid ? "Looking good!" : reason}</Typography>
                </FormControl>
                <br/>
                <LoadingButton
                    onClick={() => {lookupName()}}
                    endIcon={<SearchRoundedIcon />}
                    loading={shouldLoad}
                    loadingPosition="end"
                    variant="contained"
                    color="secondary" sx={{minHeight: 50, minWidth: 120}}
                    disabled={!isValid || name === ''}
                >
                    Look up
                </LoadingButton>
                <Typography variant="h3" sx={{fontWeight: 800, paddingTop : 5}}>Vinu<Typography display="inline" variant="h3" sx={{fontWeight: 800, color: '#006aff'}}>Pay </Typography></Typography>
                <Typography variant="h5" sx={{fontWeight: 700, mt: 5}} color="error">NOTICE: The displaying of the result of the lookup will most likely be changed in future versions. Happy to hear your feedback :) </Typography>
            </Box>

        </Container>

        {/* Name "output" panel */}
        <Container sx={{paddingTop: 3}}>
            {nameData !== null? <NamePanel name={nameData.name} nameId={nameData.nameId} owner={nameData.ownerAddress} isVerified={name.isTrusted}  canManage={false} style={{paddingTop: 5}}/> : ''}
        </Container>
    </div>
)
```

Some screenshots of the issue:

[image: As you see on the "right side" of the view, the different grey colour appears, and that is the place where the element overflows.]

As you see on the "right side" of the view, the different grey colour appears, and that is the place where the element overflows.

You can view the issue here: https://dev.vinu.cash/nameLookup (visible on mobile devices, on chrome selecting Galaxy S8+ (360x740) device to view on also shows the issue.